# What happen before the Devil King of the Sixth Heaven create Samsara?

Tags: rebirth, samsara, wheel-of-life

What i want to ask is what is the life before the Devil King of the Sixth Heaven create Samsara (know as wheel-of-life,cycle-of-birth) and law of causation

Comment: Mara does not create Samsara. Where did you get that from?

Comment: Yes he is he the one tried to prevent buddha to become buddha and he also the one who create Samsara

Comment: No he does not create Samsara.

Comment: is this buddhism question? or based on some book?

Answer (score 1):

This is an understandable confusion of 2 mythical concepts:

[Samsara] is the wheel of rebirth, divided into 6 realms:

- Niraya (hell)
- Preta (hungry ghosts)
- Tiryak (animals )
- Manushya (humans)
- Asura (demi-gods)
- Devas (deities)

[The Six Heavens of the World of Desire](http://chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/index.php?title=Six_heavens_of_the_world_of_desire) are 6 places between earth and the Brahma heaven:

- Chatur-maharaja-kayika (Heaven of the 4 heavenly kings)
- Trayatrimsha (Heaven of the Thirty-three Gods)
- Yama Heaven
- Tushita (Heaven of Contentment)
- Nirmanarati (Heaven of Enjoying the Conjured)
- Paranirmita-vasha-vartin (Heaven of Freely Enjoying Things Conjured by Others)

The “Heaven of the Devil King” (Māra  in Sanskrit) resides in Paranirmita-vasha-vartin. Māra enjoys making free use of the desires of others to manipulate and control others according to their own will. The founder of the Nichiren lineage wrote:

> This world is the province of the Devil of the Sixth Heaven.  All of
>   its people have been his karmic associates since time without
>   beginning

Since manipulating someone's desire will have karmic consequences, this can be *associated* with Samsara, but the Devil King did not *create* Samsara, nor is it recorded who is assumed to have created the Six Heavens.

Answer (score 0):

Beings, Samsara rolls on driven by craving and ignorance. A beginning point can not be traced... If wishing to use a synonym, Mara, for this very "craving and ignorance", inwardly, outwardly, it, the Buddhas state on the issue "begining", should fit for a clear answer.

*[Note: this here is not meant for any trade, exchange, stakes... what ever purpose of gains for the world. If not given to give in such way, it might be proper to be deleted]*